# Handling Single and Multiple Json data

Tags: c#, json.net

I have json string output as below, this is single item, there can be multiple of items as well.

```
[{"name":"someName","id":10,"state":"someState"}]
```

when i try to deserialize above json string using `JsonConvert` i get below error.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 because the type requires
>   a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this
>   error either change the  JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change
>   the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a
>   primitive type  like integer, not a collection type like an array or
>   List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.

Here is code block,

`string response = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; // gives json string 
var result1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response); // this works
var result2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(response); // gets error here`

since json string can have single or multiple items, i cant use RootObject while deserializing.

RootObject class looks like

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("state")]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried using `custom JsonConverter` at property level and class level of RootObject class, referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n) , but couldn't figure out how to use same in my case, appreciate if anyone could help me here.

Comment: json can not give you a list. its always give you a string

Comment: yes, here list of items i meant multiple items in response. anyways, edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, why you are saying the code is not working and it's throwing error.
I tried to  regenerate the issue but it seems to be working fine form me.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string json="[{\"name\":\"someName\",\"id\":10,\"state\":\"someState\"},{\"name\":\"someName\",\"id\":10,\"state\":\"someState\"}]";
            string json2="[{\"name\":\"someName\",\"id\":10,\"state\":\"someState\"}]";
            var result1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
            var result2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json2);
            Console.WriteLine("result1 count="+result1.Count());
            Console.WriteLine("result2 count="+result2.Count());

        }



    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("state")]
        public string State { get; set; }
    }
```

Dotnet Fiddle [**Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CcZ2IB)

Comment: Thanks for your time. Finally found the problem, is due to type of json output which i was getting from an api call, few a times output from api is just a single item `'{"name":"someName","id":10,"state":"someState"}' ` and not `'[{"name":"someName","id":10,"state":"someState"}]'` as i posted, apologies.